# Django cannot find settings?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Everything was working before but all of a sudden

```
python manage.py runserver
```

throws an error

```
line 41, in import_module
return sys.modules[name]
KeyError: 'settings.base'
```

my PYTHONPATH is pointing to the root folder of my django project.

my manage.py is:

```
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.base")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I have a settings folder in which I have the base.py file. That file pulls in environment specific settings.

```
if os.getenv("PLATFORM") == "Heroku-Master":
        from .heroku_master import *
    elif os.getenv("PLATFORM") == "Heroku-Dev":
        from .heroku_dev import *
    elif os.getenv("PLATFORM") == "Heroku-Prod":
        from .heroku_prod import *
    else:
        from .local import *
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Errr... that `settings.base` doesn't exist.

Comment: I have a settings folder inside the root which has a base.py file.

Comment: Does your settings folder have a `__init__.py`? Is your root folder on the python path?

Comment: Yes my settings folder has  __ init __.py  and PYTHONPATH contains the path to the projects root folder

Answer (score 0):

Is your file named settings.py?

Suppose that your project root is on /home/username/workspace/ProjectDjango and you have the following structure:

```
workspace
    ProjectDjango
        manage.py
        YourAppFolder
            settings.py
```

Your config should be:

```
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "YourAppFolder.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: No I have a folder called settings. In that I have a base.py file that has the common 'settings' and pulls in environment specific 'settings' file for local/dev/prod.try. See above.

Comment: So it reaches base.py if/else structure? If so, did you test if the try/except block is succeeding on reading os.getenv("PLATFORM")?